# Calabash-android: Inaccurate touch when trying to touch elements on pop-up window

Tags: android, touch, calabash, calabash-android

I’m facing an issue with touching on elements.

The issue occur when a pop-up window appears and when I’m pressing on one of the buttons nothing happen.

- The query recognize the element.
- This issue occur on physical device only (never saw that issue on the Genymotion).
- It is not always happening.
- After playing around (queries, touches, etc.) it is works fine, but happen again if I re-open the app.
- Trying to touch it by ‘* text’ or ‘* id’ and got the same results.
- Configure the device to show the touches and it is showing a wrong position when pressing.

Is that a known issue with Calabash?

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it sounds like a known issue with Android, which is seen in Calabash-Android when working with floating dialogues and keyboards (which is why the issue probably does not occur when using Genymotion). We have described workarounds in greater detail [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/Hot-Topics) in the Calabash-Android wiki. What happens is that the view coordinates of the floating dialogue are not updated when they keyboard is shown/hidden and visually pushes the dialogue upwards and downwards.

Comment: thx!!!! -- that's working!!! --- in my case the keyboard is hiding a split second after the window is pop up and that cause the issue. if i hide the keyboard before, i able to press the button.

Comment: Great, do you mind marking this answer as correct for others to see?